# Cannot resolve symbol 'NotBlank'?

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I just began my spring boot yestoday, but cannot resolve symbol 'NotBlank'. I tried to restart , reimport, can someone tell me how to solve this problem plz.

Comment: Welcome to So. Please do share a little a bit more of what you are facing, what build tool are using, your build file etc.

Comment: Are you using spring boot 2.3.0 version ?

Comment: I ues intelij idea and my spring boot version is 2.4.0

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adding `spring-boot-starter-validation` to your project will likely fix this problem.

with Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

with Gradle:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
}
```

Comment: Finally restarting the IDE worked.

Answer (score 0):

If the answer mentioned by @scott Frederick didn't work for you. Change your imports from

**javax**.validation.constraints.NotNull;

to

import **jakarta**.validation.constraints.NotNull;